# Receiving Incorrect Entity Results

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, lambda, entity

I have two tables: owners and clients, which have a 1 to many association. Trying to fine tune my Entity learning, I ran into a snag. All day, without any luck, I have tried reasoning trough these two similar lines of code return different values:

Testing purposes only, I’m trying to total clients per owner. Owners entity has a Clients navigation returning a collection of Client objects. I would like to have the results include the Owners entity, which would include the Clients entity.

I would like to know why these three ways returning the total number of clients are different. The first and second return zero clients and the third return the correct total of clients.

Returns Zero Clients:

```
Owner owner = context.Owners.First(o => o.ownerID == 5);
var clients = owner.Clients.Count();
```

-

```
Owner owner = context.Owners.Where(o => o.ownerID == 5).FirstOrDefault();
var clients = owner.Clients.Count();
```

Returns Correct Count

```
var clients = context.Owners.Where(o => o.ownerID == 5).Select(o => o.Clients.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

I hope to find an explaination why things are so different.

Thank you

Comment: Is lazy loading enabled? It seems that it may not be. In that case you would want to use .Include to load entities eagerly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pawel says, this must be related to lazy loading. The absence of, that is. I assume that your `Owner` class creates its own `Clients` collection (in its constructor, I think) otherwise it would be null.

Now if you define the `Clients` collection as virtual (assuming you work code-first), EF will be able to lazy load it when you address `owner.Clients.Count()`.